# Gym reports error when I import "MsPacman-v4" game (about ROMs?)

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I tried to use "MsPacman-v4" as my environment of agent, but my python reported me the following message.

```
    gym.error.Error: We're Unable to find the game "MsPacman". Note: Gym no longer 
distributes ROMs. If you own a license to use the necessary ROMs for research purposes
 you can download them via `pip install gym[accept-rom-license]`. Otherwise, you should
 try importing "MsPacman" via the command `ale-import-roms`. If you believe this is a 
mistake perhaps your copy of "MsPacman" is unsupported. To check if this is the case try 
providing the environment variable `PYTHONWARNINGS=default::ImportWarning:ale_py.roms`. 
For more information see: https://github.com/mgbellemare/Arcade-Learning-Environment#rom-
management
```

then I tried the command recommanded above in the terminal

```
pip install gym[accept-rom-license]
```

it started to download, but then reported error either...

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-
packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-628u67c4
/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i 
https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel requests tqdm click 'importlib-resources; 
python_version < '"'"'3.9'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

what should I do to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

!pip install gym[atari]

!pip install gym[accept-rom-license]

import gym

env = gym.make("ALE/MsPacman-v5")

I hope this will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).